unable to control brightness [in ubuntu 23.10 with i3wm]
I have tried everything all solutions available on this forum and others, but unable to solve this problem.
Things are working fine in ubuntu classic, but when I switch to i3 things are going haywire. I am using NVIDIA Driver version: 542.29.06.

have tried using xfce4/light/xrandr but not working. xrandr is just fading out the colors
I added acpi_backlight=video/none/… acpi_osi=linux to /etc/default/grub
I added RegistryDwords” “EnableBrightnessControl=1 to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

Also tried adding the brightness control setting in the i3 config but this doesn't work too.
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
